# How can I change the x-axis labels in a Python plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this code :

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
b = np.exp(a)
plt.plot(a,b,'.')
plt.show()
```

The code works fine, but I need to modify the x-axis labels of the plot.
I would like the x-axis labels to be all powers of 10 according to the `a` axis inputs. for the example code, it would be like [10^1, 10^2, ..., 10^10].

I would appreciate any suggestions.

Thank you !

Comment: once you have created b from a, do not give a  as argument to plot() rather another array, c, which contains the powers of 10 you seek

Comment: I try this `c = np.array([10^i for i in a])`but I don't see 10^1 and the others

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
# this is it, but better use floats like 10.0, 
# a integer might not hold values that big
b = 10.0 ** a 
plt.plot(a,b,'.')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

This code probably is what you need:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt

a = np.asarray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
b = np.exp(a)
c = np.asarray([10**i for i in a])
print(list(zip(a,c)))
plt.xticks(a, c)
plt.plot(a,b,'.')
plt.show()
```

By using `plt.xtick()` you can customize your x-label of plot. I also replaced `10^i` with `10**i`.