# How to list Kivy-Garden Graph x_axis major_tick labels with string value?

Tags: python, android, graph, kivy

This is my first post! Please forgive me should I misstep in any way ...
I had been trying to replace the x_axis major_tick label value with the short name of each month in the Kivy_Garden.Graph for the last week and still have not found a solution. So far, I have managed to use the number of each month, but this is not ideal. Below is my code taken from an example page (Thanks [Tshirtman]) modified with my own Data examples ...

Please ignore my many Comments they are my many "casualties" of trial&errors ...

Any help pointing me in the right direction is most appreciated ...

```
import operator
import calendar
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivymd.material_resources import DEVICE_TYPE
from kivy_garden.graph import Graph, MeshLinePlot, LinePlot
# __all__ = ('Graph', 'Plot', 'MeshLinePlot', 'MeshStemPlot', 'LinePlot',
#            'SmoothLinePlot', 'ContourPlot', 'ScatterPlot', 'PointPlot')


class Plot1(RelativeLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Plot1, self).__init__(**kwargs)


        strMth = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
        # x1 = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
        x1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
        y1 = [
            1.9336837768556001,
            2.29488830566305,
            3.77081146240305,
            8.034848022459,
            12.752540588372002,
            16.601560974130003,
            19.705297851575004,
            19.410496521000006,
            15.050564575200003,
            10.397409057613501,
            5.2474151611328,
            2.57436218261685
            ]

        yData = len(y1)

        xList = list(enumerate(strMth,1))
        if DEVICE_TYPE != 'mobile': print(f'xList={xList}')
        for x in range(0, yData): 
            if DEVICE_TYPE != 'mobile': print(f'xList[x]={xList[x]}')
        # intXmin = int(min(x1))
        # intXmax = int(max(x1))
        # if DEVICE_TYPE != 'mobile': print(f'intXmin={intXmin}')
        # if DEVICE_TYPE != 'mobile': print(f'intXmax={intXmax}')

        xdict = dict(enumerate(x1))
        if DEVICE_TYPE != 'mobile': print(f'xdict={xdict}')
        for x in range(0, yData): 
            if DEVICE_TYPE != 'mobile': 
                print(f'calendar.month_abbr[x]={calendar.month_abbr[x+1]}')
                print(f'xdict[x]={xdict[x]}')

        intXmin = int(min(xdict.keys())) + 1
        intXmax = int(max(xdict.keys())) + 1
        if DEVICE_TYPE != 'mobile': print(f'intXmin={intXmin}')
        if DEVICE_TYPE != 'mobile': print(f'intXmax={intXmax}')

        intYmax = int(max(y1)) + 1
        intYmin = int(min(y1)) - 1

        intYmajor = int((intYmax - intYmin) / 4)

        degree_sign= u'\N{DEGREE SIGN}'

        self.graph = Graph(
            pos_hint={'x': 0, 'y': 0},
            # size_hint=(1, 0.9),
            # x_ticks_minor=5,
            x_ticks_major=1,
            # y_ticks_minor=1,
            y_ticks_major=intYmajor,
            x_grid=True,
            y_grid=True,
            # x_axis=strMth,
            xmin=intXmin,
            xmax=intXmax,
            ymin=intYmin,
            ymax=intYmax,
            x_grid_label=True,
            y_grid_label=True,
            xlabel='Month',
            ylabel=f'Temp ({degree_sign}C)',
            draw_border=False
        )

        self.plot = MeshLinePlot(color=[1, 0, 0, 1])
        # self.plot.points = [(x, y1[x]) for x in range(0, yData)]
        # self.plot.points = [(x, y1[x]) for x, y in enumerate(x1)]
        self.plot.points = [(x1[x], y1[x]) for x, y in enumerate(x1)]
        # self.plot.points = [(calendar.month_abbr[x], y1[x]) for x, y in enumerate(x1)]

        # strMth = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
        # strMth = [(xdict[x]) for x in range(0, yData)]
        # self.graph.x_axis = xList
        if DEVICE_TYPE != 'mobile': print(f'self.graph1.x_axis={self.graph.x_axis}\n')

        self.add_widget(self.graph)

        self.graph.add_plot(self.plot)

class Plot2(RelativeLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Plot2, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # x1 = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
        x1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
        y2 = [
            101.77287445066001,
            92.02159576423,
            70.04141540531,
            57.75453948974499,
            53.007298469540004,
            52.04727563858499,
            45.965359878535004,
            47.2860280037,
            49.18611373901,
            64.60937595366501,
            96.76075782778503,
            113.429190444945
            ]

        yData = len(y2)
        xdict = dict(enumerate(x1))
        if DEVICE_TYPE != 'mobile': print(xdict)
        for x in range(0, yData): 
            if DEVICE_TYPE != 'mobile': print(xdict[x])
        intXmin = int(min(xdict.keys())) + 1
        intXmax = int(max(xdict.keys())) + 1
        if DEVICE_TYPE != 'mobile': print(f'intXmin={intXmin}')
        if DEVICE_TYPE != 'mobile': print(f'intXmax={intXmax}')

        intYmax = int(max(y2) + 1)
        intYmin = int(min(y2) - 1)

        intYmajor = int((intYmax - intYmin) / 4)

        self.graph = Graph(
            pos_hint={'x': 0, 'y': 0},
            # size_hint=(1, 0.9),
            # x_ticks_minor=5,
            x_ticks_major=1,
            y_ticks_minor=1,
            y_ticks_major=intYmajor,
            x_grid=True,
            y_grid=True,
            x_axis=(0,x1),
            xmin=intXmin,
            xmax=intXmax,
            ymin=intYmin,
            ymax=intYmax,
            x_grid_label=True,
            y_grid_label=True,
            xlabel='Month',
            ylabel='Percipitation (mm)',
            draw_border=False
        )

        self.plot = MeshLinePlot(color=[0, 0.749, 1, 1])
        # self.plot.points = [(x, y1[x]) for x in range(0, yData)]
        # self.plot.points = [(x, y2[x]) for x, y in enumerate(x1)]
        self.plot.points = [(x1[x], y2[x]) for x, y in enumerate(x1)]

        strMth = [(xdict[x]) for x in range(0, yData)]
        self.graph.x_axis = strMth

        if DEVICE_TYPE != 'mobile': print(f'self.graph2.x_axis={self.graph.x_axis}\n')

        # self.plot2 = MeshLinePlot(color=[1, 0, 0, 1])
        # self.plot2.points = [(x, cos(x / 10.0)) for x in range(0, 101)]
        self.add_widget(self.graph)

        self.graph.add_plot(self.plot)
        # self.graph.add_plot(self.plot2)

class GraphLayoutApp(App):

    def ScreenClose_on_press(self, *args):
        print('Exiting...')
        return

    def build(self):
        Window.bind(on_request_close=self.ScreenClose_on_press)

        scroll_view = ScrollView()
        grid_layout = GridLayout(cols=1, padding=20, spacing=20, size_hint_y=None)
        grid_layout.bind(minimum_size=grid_layout.setter('size'))
        graph = Plot1(size_hint_y=None, height=300)
        graph2 = Plot2(size_hint_y=None, height=300)
        label = Label(text="Plot-1", size_hint_y=None, height=30)
        label2 = Label(text="Plot-2", size_hint_y=None, height=30)
        grid_layout.add_widget(label)
        grid_layout.add_widget(graph)
        grid_layout.add_widget(label2)
        grid_layout.add_widget(graph2)

        scroll_view.add_widget(grid_layout)
        return scroll_view

if __name__ == '__main__':
    GraphLayoutApp().run()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I am not super familiar with Kivy but have you tried using date(year, month, day) for each value instead of just integers?

Comment: @Carter, as you may see I had even tried using [(calendar.month_abbr[x]] function to convert before inserting, but it gives an error saying cannot covert a [string] to float...

Comment: Yea I think you would have to use a real date or datetime

Comment: @Carter, as suggested I tried using date.month, it returns the Month as a numeric which can be used but it is what I had managed to used so far. Much thanks for your advice in any case... I shall have to wait hoping some Kivy-Graph guru(s) or someone which the same wish and gotten a solution will come across my question and offer me some enlightenment ...cheers

Comment: Going off of this example,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940217/how-can-i-change-the-x-axis-labels-in-a-python-plot  i thought you should be able to set the plot or graph.xticks(x1,x1labels) and gett what you want.  Just a guess!

Comment: @Carter, thanks for your advice, I had tried your example and it is able to have customized x-axis tick-labels. I noticed it is using [pylab-matplotlib]. Actually I have the graph drawn using [matplotlib] and can have the x-axis with my desired labels ... but for my "final solution" ... the graph is to run on an android device and it seems [matplotlib] don't run on android device yet ... I am able to make the android pack (apk) with [buildozer] without error, the apk-APP is installable on the android device without error, but "crash out" the moment I touch run it.